# Get count of count checked checkboxes in parent container

Tags: reactjs

I have a parent component.  It loops through an array and for each item in array creates a new child component. These child components are divs with checkbox and label inside. What i would like is in the parent control to have a div that displays the number of checked checkboxes.

What is best and easiest approach for this?

Comment: it could be implemented using a simple piece of state for example `count` and set onChange handler for every input , `onChange` you increase this `count` by `1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want the count to be displayed on the parent component, you need something to keep track of it from that parent component. So I implemented count function and will pass it in as props to your children component. We will keep track of all the children components by using the Parent component's count state. See the App component in the snippet bellow.

As for the child component, all you need is a simple checkbox handler to control the checkboxes being checked or not, and when you do so, call the count function which was passed in as a props. See the Checkbox component in the snippet

```js
class Checkbox extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state ={
      checked: false
    }
  }
  handleCheck () {
    let checked = !this.state.checked
    if (checked) {
      this.props.count(true)
    } else {
      this.props.count(false)
    }
    this.setState({checked})
  }
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <label>
          {this.props.name}
          <input type='checkbox' checked={this.state.checked} onChange={() => this.handleCheck()}/>
        </label>
       </div>
    )
  }
}

class App extends React.Component{
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      count: 0
    }
  }
  
  count (checked) {
    let { count } = this.state
    if (checked) {
     count ++
  } else {
     count --
    }

    console.log(count)
    this.setState({count})
  }
  
  render(){
    const arr = ['Checkbox1', 'Checkbox2', 'Checkbox3']
    // Note: make sure to use bind on the count function since we are
    // using the state from the parent component
    return (
     <div>
        <form >
         {arr.map(a => <Checkbox name={a} count={this.count.bind(this)}/>)}
        </form>
        {this.state.count}
     </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
const checkboxItems = ["beep", "foo", "bop", "bar"];

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const { checkboxItems } = this.props;
    const checkedState = checkboxItems.reduce((acc, label) => {
      acc[label] = false;
      return acc;
    }, {});
    this.state = {
      checkedState: checkedState
    };
  }

  onChange = (e, label) => {
    this.setState({
      checkedState: {
        ...this.state.checkedState,
        [label]: e.target.checked
      }
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { checkedState } = this.state;
    const { checkboxItems } = this.props;
    const numChecked = Object.keys(checkedState).reduce((acc, key) => {
      if (checkedState[key]) acc++
      return acc
    }, 0)
    return (
      <div>
        {checkboxItems.map((label, index) => {
          return (
            <label key={index}>
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                onChange={e => this.onChange(e, label)}
                checked={checkedState[label]}
              />
              {label}
            </label>
          );
        })}
        <div>
        Number of checked inputs: {numChecked}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App checkboxItems={checkboxItems} />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```